# In-line block and Function block, What is different?

Tags: programming-languages, nested, block

In Programming Language Theory,

Block which is related with stack frame has two kinds. In-line block and function block.

What is different between **In-line block** and **function block**?

And assume there is code like below.

```
int x = 1;
g(z) = z + x;
```

According to In-line block, Is function g nested to variable x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function block :**
void func(){...};  // in c or c++

(defun func ...) // in clisp

fun func() = ... // in ml

The Function Block is the block that wraps the function.
In C, when the function returns, the function's activation records is deleted from stack.
however, In functional language like ML, CLISP, function's return don't always means deletion of stack frame.
Because the function can be used later.

**In-line block** is the block that shows nested structure.

```
int x = 1;  
g(z) = z + x;
```

When the function g uses In-line block, the function g takes the variable x as 1. the function g don't know x's value with only the function g's activation record. however the reason the function g can know x's value is it use static link, and static link points the most nearest nesting block.

The difference between function block and inline block is that function block always is not deleted from stack frame when the function returns.